# python: Task got bad yield:

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, twisted

I am aiming to make parallel requests to the list of endpoints, hence using asyncio ensure_future can somone please take a look and give me an idea on how to fix errors (python3.6.7)

```
import asyncio
import treq


async def main_aysnc():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await start_coros_parllel()

async def start_coros_parllel():
    config = {}
    config['services'] = [ 
        b'https://www.google.com',
        b'https://www.yahoo.com',
        b'https://www.facebook.com'
        ]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.ensure_future(treq.get(service)) for service in config['services']])
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main_aysnc())
```

LOGS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2cr.py", line 35, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main_aysnc())
  File "/Users/vchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 473, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "2cr.py", line 7, in main_aysnc
    await start_coros_parllel()
  File "2cr.py", line 20, in start_coros_parllel
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.ensure_future(treq.get(service)) for service in config['services']])
  File "/Users/vchauhan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 537, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <Deferred at 0x104cc5048>
```

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev  I ended up using aiohttp for making requests. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should not use `asyncio` with `treq`.

According to documentation:

> treq depends on a recent Twisted and functions on Python 2.7 and
> Python 3.3+ (including PyPy).

If you want to use `asyncio` you have to use some other http client framework e.g. aiohttp.

If you need any example on how to use aiohttp client, feel free to ask.